# What exactly does "too old to migrate" mean?

Tags: support, review-queues, vote-to-close

I just earned the **"cast close & re-open votes privilege"** recently and gained access to the two associated review queues.

So, I've been experiencing with the "Close Votes" review and noticed this message in several questions when trying to vote to close:

[image: too old to migrate]

And I'm not sure what it means exactly. Does it mean:

- "You can select a reason that *normally* migrates the question, it might lead to closing the question but it will **not** lead to migrating it." **Or...**
- "Please don't select a reason that might lead to migrating the question."

..? I'm trying to avoid this kind of questions for now but if it turned out to be the second, what exactly should we do in this case? Should we select another reason to close the question or should we leave the question open?

<sub>Note: The above questions assume that the question being reviewed *is* actually off-topic and does actually belong to another site, let's say SuperUser.</sub>

Comment: It means that the question is too old to migrate, and not even moderators can migrate it. The option is simply not shown.

Comment: I see. I didn't notice that the `This question belongs on another...` option becomes unavailable in this case, and thought that the `Questions about general computing...` option also migrates the question to SuperUser. Thanks for the clarification.